# Central orbit - Find eccentricity of the orbit

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

A particle moving in an ellipse under the action of a force towards the focus O, moves from greatest distance from O to an extremity of the minor axis in time t, and then to the least distance from O in time $\frac{t}{k}$. Show that the eccentricity of the orbit is
$$\frac{k-1}{k+1}\frac{\pi}{2}.$$

Approach:

Let the equation of an ellipse with focus as a pole is $$\frac{l}{r}=1+e \cos{\theta}$$

We know that law of force with focus as center of force is $$F=\frac{\mu}{r^2}$$

Let ACA' and BCB' are the major and minor axes of the ellipse, C being center. Given the particle moves from A' (as it is at the greatest distance from O) to B in time t and particle takes time t/k to move from B to A (as it is the least distance from O).

Now how to find the eccentricity?

Comment: Use the fact that $\frac{dS}{dt}=Constant$ where $dS$ is the surface swept in interval $dt$. I would really like to help but I think if you posted a picture it would be helpful.

Comment: @OussamaBoussif Please help. I have explained the fig. Suppose A is left of center to the ellipse. Then every thing about the problem will be clear.

Comment: Okay I think I got it now. Just wait for the solution. But I will use some properties of the ellipse that I wont explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first let's define some properties of the ellipse to be used in this problem:

$a$ defines the semi major axis.

$b$ defines the semi minor axis.

$e$ is the eccentricity.

$2c$ is the distance between the two fociis.

$S$ is the total surface of the ellipse

We have the following relations:

$$
S=\pi ab\\
e=\frac{c}{a}
$$

Now I you know Kepler second law that states that the surface swept at in different time intervals are equal or:

$$
\frac{dS}{dt}=Constant
$$

Let $S_1$ the surface swept from $A'$ to $B$ in the interval $t$. Ans $S_2$ be the surface swept from $B$ to $A$ in the interval $\frac{t}{k}$, so using kepler second law:

Here is a (picture)[http://i72.fastpic.ru/big/2015/0905/ae/eab21b69f3d76bbdeaab189f4fa6f2ae.jpg]

$$
\frac{S_1}{t}=\frac{S_2}{\frac{t}{k}}\\
S_1=kS_2
$$

Let's calculate $S_1$ :

I don't have a figure now but I hope you understand. We note that $S_1$ is made of a quarter ellipse plus the right triangle $COB$.

So $S_1$ is the sum of the area of a quarter ellipse plus the are of the triangle hence:

$$
S_1=\frac{\pi ab}{4}+\frac{CB\times OC}{2}
$$

But $BC=b$ and $OC=c$

So :

$$
S_1=\frac{\pi ab}{4}+\frac{bc}{2}\\
S_1=\frac{\pi ab}{4}+\frac{abe}{2}\\
S_1=ab(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{e}{2})
$$

Now for $S_2$ note that it is made of a quarter ellipse minus the same latter triangle $COB$. So it would be the same as $S_1$ except that we use a minus instead of a plus:

$$
S_2=ab(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{e}{2})
$$

Now returning to the formula obtained by kepler law:

$$
S_1=kS_2\\
ab(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{e}{2})=kab(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{e}{2})\\
\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{e}{2}=k\frac{\pi}{4}-k\frac{e}{2}\\
\frac{\pi}{2}+e=k\frac{\pi}{2}-ke\\
e(k+1)=\frac{\pi}{2}(k-1)\\
e=\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{k-1}{k+1}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What is O' that you have taken? I have taken the center as C and RHS focus is given as O. A figure will be better to understand.

Comment: Ah okay well $O$ it is I'm going to edit that

Comment: @rama_ran I will see if I can add an image

Comment: That will be very nice then. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. I uploaded the image. Dont forget to accept the answer if you found it helpful.